# Object-oriented access to fill_between shaded region in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, fill

I'm trying to get access to the shaded region of a matplotlib plot, so that I can remove it without doing `plt.cla()` [since `cla()` clears the whole axis including axis label too]

If I were plotting I line, I could do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = plt.gca()
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_xlabel('My Label Here')

# then to remove the line, but not the axis label
ax.lines.pop()
```

However, for plotting a region I execute:

```
ax.fill_between(x, 0, y)
```

So `ax.lines` is empty.

How can I clear this shaded region please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_between) states `fill_between` returns a `PolyCollection` instance. Collections are stored in `ax.collections`. So

```
ax.collections.pop()
```

should do the trick.

However, I think you have to be careful that you remove the right thing, in case there are multiple objects in either `ax.lines` or `ax.collections`. You could save a reference to the object so you know which one to remove:

```
fill_between_col = ax.fill_between(x, 0, y)
```

and then to remove:

```
ax.collections.remove(fill_between_col)
```

**EDIT**: Yet another method, and probably the best one: All the artists have a method called [`remove`](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html?highlight=artist#matplotlib.artist.Artist.remove) which does exactly what you want:

```
fill_between_col.remove()
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful comment. Trying to manually pop them by name is a good idea, although it doesn't seem to work. If I do:
my_line = ax.plot(x,y);

my_line.pop()

This does not remove the line (even after forcing a redraw of the canvas using draw())

Comment: That is not what I suggested. You can't call `pop()` on an artist you have to call: `ax.lines.remove(my_line)`. And by the way: `ax.plot` always returns a list (since you can plot multiple lines at once), so you should use `my_line = ax.plot(x,y)[0]`